# How to get JSON data after button click

Tags: javascript

```js
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
        {
            "Code": "A-0-2",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803073996.jpg",
            "Title": "Revell 07399 VW Samba Bus Model Kit",
            "Price": "$38",
            "InStock": "8"
        },
    ]
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach((product) => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc">
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart();">
                <button id="addToCart" > Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`; 
    })
}
getProducts(); 

function addToCart() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("itemName").innerText)
}
```

```html
<div class="Sheet">
    </div>
```

All right, the add to cart button only logs the first data in my object. No matter which one I press it's always the first one. I tried .val and no luck. How can I log the item that was pressed instead?

Comment: You're reusing the same ID `<h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>`

Comment: one is a class one is a ID. Whats wrong with that

Comment: Your code is open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Reusing the same ID will always return the first element with that ID

Comment: That ID is the same for all the products, you can include a counter at the end of the ID and select the products with a loop

Comment: @Dai, I am sure this is just a mock to support the question. If not, there are multiple things that needs to change before it can be released. Kiro care to weigh in?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name of product as an argument to the `addToCart()` function
like below

```
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
        {
            "Code": "A-0-2",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803073996.jpg",
            "Title": "Revell 07399 VW Samba Bus Model Kit",
            "Price": "$38",
            "InStock": "8"
        },
    ]
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach((product) => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc">
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart(product.Title);">
                <button id="addToCart" > Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`; 
    })
}
getProducts(); 

function addToCart(productTitle) {
    console.log(productTitle)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the product's `index` as a parameter to the `AddToCart()` function.

**Advantages of this implementation**

1. Allows you to access other properties of the product's object like `Price`, `InStock`, etc.
2. If you change the property name of "Title" to something else, you only need to update the `AddToCart` function code, not the `getProducts()`'s `AddToCart` call-to-action.

*Advice: You should try to avoid fetching items via html `id` or `innerText` (this was a norm a decade or more ago, not anymore). Try using more of [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)*

```js
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
        {
            "Code": "A-0-2",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803073996.jpg",
            "Title": "Revell 07399 VW Samba Bus Model Kit",
            "Price": "$38",
            "InStock": "8"
        },
    ]
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach((product, productIndex) => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc">
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="addToCart(`+productIndex+`);">
                <button id="addToCart" > Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`; 
    })
}
getProducts(); 

function addToCart(productIndex) {
    var product = Sheet[productIndex];
    console.log(product.Title);
}
```

```html
<div class="Sheet">
    </div>
```

**Explanation**

The parameters of a `forEach` function allows for the index of the current iteration. [read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
   const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
        {
            "Code": "A-0-2",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803073996.jpg",
            "Title": "Revell 07399 VW Samba Bus Model Kit",
            "Price": "$38",
            "InStock": "8"
        },
    ]
    const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");

    function getProducts() {
        Sheet.forEach((product) => {
            productsEl.innerHTML += `<div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src=${product.UPC} alt="Image Unavailable" height="170px;" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemdesc" >
                <h2 class="itemName" id="itemName">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price"><span id="price">${product.Price}</span></h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p id="desc">${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart" onclick="">
                <button class="addToCartBtn" id="${product.Code}"> Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
    </div>`;
        })
    }
    getProducts();

    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".addToCartBtn");
    elements.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            console.log(e.target.id);
            //other function
        });
    });
```

```html
<div class="Sheet">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead...

```js
const productsEl = document.querySelector(".Sheet");
const Sheet = [
        {
            "Code": "A-0-1", 
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803054728.jpg",
            "Title": "U.S.S. Constitution",
            "Price": "$34",
            "InStock": "7"
        },
        {
            "Code": "A-0-2",
            "UPC": "Photos/4009803073996.jpg",
            "Title": "Revell 07399 VW Samba Bus Model Kit",
            "Price": "$38",
            "InStock": "8"
        },
    ];

(function getProducts() {
    Sheet.forEach(product => {
        productsEl.innerHTML += `<!-- ${product.Title} -->
        <div class="productContainer">
            <div class="img">
                <img src="${product.UPC}" alt="${product.Title}" height="170px" width="170px">
            </div>
            <div class="itemDesc">
                <h2 class="name">${product.Title}</h2>
                <h4 class="price">${product.Price}</h4>
                <div class="desc">
                    <p>${product.Code}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="stock">
                    <p> ${product.InStock} Units</p>
            </div>
            <div class="addToCart">
                <!-- This will ensure you're only getting the current product (via the button) -->
                <button onclick="addToCart(this)"> Add to Cart</button>
            </div>
        </div>`; 
    })
})();

function addToCart(button) {
    const parent = button.closest('.productContainer');
        // This will travel up the DOM chain from the button to the nearest element with `class="... productContainer ..."`
    const element = parent.querySelector('.name');
        // This will travel back down the DOMchain to the element with `class="... name ..."`

    console.log(element.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="Sheet"></div>
```